# HTML Button Group: how to handle margin overwrite

Tags: html, css

I´m building a button group class, as follows:

```
.ux-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: -4px;
}

.ux-button-group button:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}


.ux-button-group button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:only-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.ux-button-group button:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border: 1px Black solid;
    margin: 0px;
}  

button:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

And a simple usage:

```
<div class='ux-button-group'>
  <button input='text'>Button 1</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 2</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

All fine, expept that when I hover the mouse the button elements right margins are not being shown in red, except for the last button.

Please check the bahaviour [at this FIDDLE here.](http://jsfiddle.net/aL4xx3st/1/)

Naturally this is happening because I have 2 buttons sharing the same margin (right margin of one button and left margin of next button are in the same position on screen).

I tought using z-index would solve that, but it had no affect.

How can I solve that problem and let the margin be coloured accordingly on hover?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `z-index` solution is one step towards a correct solution: but remember that it will only work when the elements it is applied to **is anything other than `position: static`** (which is the default style). As long as you:

1. Assign `position: relative` to the buttons
2. Remove `z-index: -1` from the buttons

then things will work:

```css
.ux-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0; 
  position: relative;
  margin: -4px;
}

.ux-button-group button:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}


.ux-button-group button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:only-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.ux-button-group button:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border: 1px Black solid;
    margin: 0px;
}  

button:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='ux-button-group'>
  <button input='text'>Button 1</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 2</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

p/s: On a side note, using `display: inline` and an arbitrarily designated negative margin in order to eliminate whitespace between elements is generally a very flimsy way of making elements appear horizontally on the list. You can use float or flexbox:

#### Example with float:

In this version of an improved example, you make sure to clear the float in the parent: this can be done by either setting `overflow: hidden` or using the good old clear fix hack.

```
.ux-button-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ux-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0; 
  float: left;        /* Use this to float your buttons */
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
.ux-button-group {
  /* Prevents parent's dimensions from collapsing */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ux-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0; 
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.ux-button-group button:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}


.ux-button-group button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:only-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.ux-button-group button:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border: 1px Black solid;
    margin: 0px;
}  

button:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='ux-button-group'>
  <button input='text'>Button 1</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 2</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

#### Example with flexbox:

In this second version of an improved example, you simply make use of CSS flexbox :)

```
.ux-button-group {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.ux-button-group {
  display: flex;
}

.ux-button-group button {
  border-radius: 0; 
  position: relative;
}

.ux-button-group button:first-child {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}


.ux-button-group button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.ux-button-group button:only-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

.ux-button-group button:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    border: 1px Black solid;
    margin: 0px;
}  

button:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='ux-button-group'>
  <button input='text'>Button 1</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 2</button>
  <button input='text'>Button 3</button>
</div>
```